# Vector drawable display issues for Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

I have a list of items that I want to iterate through one at a time via clicks and display its content in a composable:

```
if (
    gameTopicsItems.value.isNotEmpty()
) {
    GameTopicItem(
        modifier = modifier,
        gameTopic = gameTopicsItems.value[currentIndexState.value],
        showPreviousIcon = currentIndexState.value > 0,
        showNextIcon = currentIndexState.value < gameTopicsItems.value.lastIndex,
        onNextClick = { currentIndexState.value += 1 },
        onPreviousClick = { currentIndexState.value -= 1 },
        showShuffleIcon = gameTopicsItems.value.size > 1,
        onShuffleClick = {
            currentIndexState.value = gameTopicsItems.value.indices.random()
        }
    )
} else {
    EmptyItemsView(modifier = modifier.padding(top = paddingNormal))
}
```

So far this logic is working fine, but the issue is on displaying the item drawable. I have an image in the item composable that displays the image from drawable res like shown below:

```
    Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .constrainAs(gameTopicIcon) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .padding(
            start = paddingXxl1,
            end = paddingXxl1,
            top = paddingXxl2
        ),
    painter = painterResource(
        id = gameTopic.icon
    ),
    contentDescription = gameTopic.title,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
)
```

The issue I have is, upon iterating the list a few times, the images(which are vectors) start to be displayed weirdly as shown in the screenshots below. What could be the issue?

[image: Expected image]
[image: Distorted image]

Comment: Found a related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202863204

Answer (score 3):

Use image painter with key, like:

```
Image(
    painter = key(gameTopic.icon) { painterResource(gameTopic.icon) },
    contentDescription = null
)
```

Comment: I found workaround here: https://github.com/blipinsk/issue-compose-painterResource/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/barteklipinski/issuecomposepainterresource/Screen.kt#L60

Comment: Hey just got here. This fixed it for me! But why does this work?